# Do regex implementations actually need a split() function?

Tags: regex, split, match, lookbehind

Is there any application for a regex `split()` operation that could not be performed by a single `match()` (or `search()`, `findall()` etc.) operation?

For example, instead of doing

```
subject.split('[|]')
```

you could get the same result with a call to

```
subject.findall('[^|]*')
```

And in nearly all regex engines (except .NET and JGSoft), `split()` *can't* do some things like "split on `|` unless they are escaped `\|`" because you'd need to have unlimited repetition inside lookbehind.

So instead of having to do something quite unreadable like this (nested lookbehinds!)

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\|");
```

you can simply do (even in JavaScript which doesn't support *any* kind of lookbehind)

```
result = subject.match(/(?:\\.|[^|])*/g);
```

This has led me to wondering: Is there *anything* at all that I can do in a `split()` that's impossible to achieve with a single `match()`/`findall()` instead? I'm willing to bet there isn't, but I'm probably overlooking something.

(I'm defining "regex" in the modern, non-regular sense, i. e., using everything that modern regexes have at their disposal like backreferences and lookaround.)

Comment: One could replace `split` with `find` and `substr` ... so why does `split` exist? (Also, `split` is not always a function of the "regex engine", even if the `split` function uses or can use regular expressions.)

Comment: It's clearly a more intuitive and better fitting function if you just want to split a string on some simple delimiter. Btw `(?:\\\||[^|])*` will not do the same thing as the .NET expression you show, eg `foo\\|bar`. `(?:[^|\\]+|\\.)*` would work better.

Comment: @Qtax: Yes, surely `split()` is a very welcome form of "syntactic sugar" in many cases. I'm just wondering if it's more than that. Thanks for noticing the error in my regex; I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of regular expressions is to describe the syntax of a language. These regular expressions can then be used to find strings that match the syntax of these languages. That’s it.

What you actually do with the matches, depends on your needs. If you’re looking for all matches, repeat the find process and collect the matches. If you want to split the string, repeat the find process and split the input string at the position the matches where found.

So basically, regular expression libraries can only do one thing: perform a search for a match. Anything else are just extensions.

A good example for this is JavaScript where there is [`RegExp.prototype.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) that actually performs the match search. Any other method that accepts regular expression (e. g. `RegExp.prototype.test`, `String.prototype.match`, `String.prototype.search`) just uses the basic functionality of `RegExp.prototype.exec` somehow:

```
// pseudo-implementations
RegExp.prototype.test = function(str) {
    return RegExp(this).exec(str);
};
String.prototype.match = function(pattern) {
    return RegExp(pattern).exec(this);
};
String.prototype.search = function(pattern) {
    return RegExp(pattern).exec(this).index;
};
```